# No love for 2 and 3

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Form two numbers. The sum of them must be $100$.

For the first one you must use the digits $4$, $5$ and $6$ taken exactly once in this order. You cannot use other digits.

For the second one you must use the digits $7$, $8$ and $9$ taken exactly once in this order. You cannot use other digits.

The operations you may use for forming each of the numbers are $x + y$, $x - y$, $x \times y$ and $x \div y$. <sub>Division is math division, you cannot use computer integer division where `4/5 = 0`. Operator precedence is respected. Each operation may be used multiple times</sub>

You cannot use other symbols (except $456789+-\times\div)$

---

Example:

- 1st number: $4\times5-6$
- 2nd number: $7+89$

Sum is wrong $14+96=110 \neq 100$, but everything else is ok.

Comment: the titles holds no clues. It's just fun (or lack of inspiration, take it as you will). It alludes to the fact that the digits $2$ and $3$ are the only ones not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $ 45_{6} = 29 $
>  $ 78_{9} = 71 $
>  $ 29 + 71 = 100 $

Comment: Excellent! Probably the expected answer

Comment: Yes, that's my solution. Congratulations!

Answer (score 13):

Implementing lateral thinking

> The question does not specify which base, $B$, we are in. Only that we are using the digits $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$ and $9$ so this means that $B \geq 10$. I will assume $B=12$ so that we additionally have the digits $a$ and $b$.

Then one answer is

> $4 \times 5 \times 6 = a0$ 
>  $7+8+9 = 20$ 
>  $a0 + 20 = 100$

Comment: not the solution I had in mind but it does respects all the requirements. As far as I am concerned it's correct and it's the best solution yet.

Answer (score 8):

That should work:

> Number 1: $4 \times (-5 + 6) = 4$
>  Number 2: $7 + 89 = 96  $

Comment: Nice answer!! :D

Comment: Negation isn't in the list of allowed operations though.

Comment: From my understanding, negation and "(", ")" are not allowed.
So this should be wrong.

Comment: Good try. However, parenthesis aren't allowed because you can't use their symbols `(` `)`. Also, negation even if it uses the allowed symbol $-$ isn't an operation you can use.

Comment: Sorry all, I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score 8):

With a bit of lateral thinking:

> 1st number: $ 4 \times 5 - 6 = 14 $
>  2nd number: $ 7 - 8 - 9 = -10 $
>
>  $ 14 + (-10) = 4 $
>
>  Decimal to Binary: $ (4)_{10} = (100)_{2} $

Comment: I like your answer. A step in the right direction. And your answer confirms that the lateral thinking tag is appropriate.

Comment: Wait, so this is not your expected answer?

Comment: no, it's not the answer I had in mind

Comment: Hmmm, ok.
How about a small hint: Do we need multiple numeral systems for your solution?

Answer (score 6):

With some brute force I can confirm what we thought already: we do need some lateral thinking to solve this challenge!

In bash, try all combinations of operators (+, -, * and / and the concatenate character which is an empty string: ' '). No negation, no brackets.

Then print the ones where the outcome is between 95 and 105:

```
for a in + - \* / ''; do
    for b in + - \* / ''; do
        for c in + - \* / ''; do
            for d in + - \* / ''; do
                echo 4${a}5${b}6 + 7${c}8${d}9 = $(echo "scale=3 ; 4${a}5${b}6 + 7${c}8${d}9" | bc)
            done
        done
    done
done | awk '$NF>95 && $NF<105,1'
```

Output:

```
4+5+6 + 78+9 = 102
4+5-6 + 7+89 = 99
4+5*6 + 7*8+9 = 99
4+5*6 + 78-9 = 103
4+5/6 + 7+89 = 100.833
4-5+6 + 7+89 = 101
4-5/6 + 7+89 = 99.167
4*5-6 + 78+9 = 101
4*5/6 + 7+89 = 99.333
4/5+6 + 7+89 = 102.800
4/5*6 + 7+89 = 100.800
4/5/6 + 7+89 = 96.133
4/56 + 7+89 = 96.071
45+6 + 7*8-9 = 98
45-6 + 7*8+9 = 104
45/6 + 7+89 = 103.500
```

So no luck here yet!

Comment: Also, $(4\times 5 + 6)+(78-9)=95$ is another close one :D

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is what you're looking for, and is really stretching the limits of interpreting what you said, but:

`1st number: 4×5−6
2nd number: 7+89`

Now, only using the allowed digits, the sum of `4` (1 is not an allowed symbol and therefore 14 becomes 4) and `96` is **100**

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [npkllr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52320/npkllr)'s answer

> $- 4 + 5 - 6 = - 5$
>  $78 - 9 = 69$
>  $-5 + 69 = 64$
>  $DEC(64) = OCT(100)$

Comment: Negation isn’t allowed

Answer (score 0):

> 4*5/6 = 3.33 
>  7+89 = 96 
>  
>  3.33 + 96 ≈ 100

Comment: Welcome to puzzling.SE! Unfortunately, the result must be exactly 100 (moreover 99.333 ≈ 99, not 100).

Comment: @xhienne if ≈ stands for "approximately equal to", or "almost equal to" why is 99.333 ≈ 100 wrong? its still almost equal to the 99.333. ≈ does not mean round down. And even so, i could also go with 99 ≈ 100. Regardless of wether the sum is exactly 100.